# How does glusterfs create volume when the heketi endpoint is not in the same namespace as pv and PVC

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, kubernetes-pod, glusterfs

I have two namespaces 'runsdata' and 'monitoring'. The heketi pod and glusterfs's daemonSet pod are both under the 'runsdata' namespace.  Now I want to create the Prometheus monitor under the 'monitoring' namespace. Since I need storage to store my Prometheus data. So I create PVC(under the 'monitoring' ns) and pv, And in the PVC yaml I declare storageclass to create the corresponding volume in order to provide storage for Prometheus. But when I created pvc bound with pv and apply the prometheus-server.yaml . I get the error:

```
  Warning  FailedMount       18m (x3 over 43m)     kubelet, 172.16.5.151  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[prometheus-data-volume], unattached volumes=[prometheus-rules-volume prometheus-token-vcrr2 prometheus-data-volume prometheus-conf-volume]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount       13m (x5 over 50m)     kubelet, 172.16.5.151  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[prometheus-data-volume], unattached volumes=[prometheus-token-vcrr2 prometheus-data-volume prometheus-conf-volume prometheus-rules-volume]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount       3m58s (x35 over 59m)  kubelet, 172.16.5.151  MountVolume.NewMounter initialization failed for volume "data-prometheus-pv" : endpoints "heketi-storage-endpoints" not found
```

It's not difficult to know from the above log, the storageClass can not found the heketi endpoints to create volume. because the heketi endpoints is under the 'runsdata'. how can i solve this problem?

Other info: 
1. pv and pvc

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: data-prometheus-pv
  labels:
    pv: data-prometheus-pv
    release: stable
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  storageClassName: runsdata-static-class
  glusterfs:
    endpoints: "heketi-storage-endpoints"
    path: "runsdata-glusterfs-static-class"
    readOnly: true

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: data-prometheus-claim
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
  storageClassName: runsdata-static-class
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pv: data-prometheus-pv
      release: stable
```

---

```
[root@localhost online-prometheus]# kubectl get pv
    NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                              STORAGECLASS            REASON   AGE
    data-config-pv                             1Gi        RWX            Retain           Bound    runsdata/data-config-claim         runsdata-static-class            5d22h
    data-mongo-pv                              1Gi        RWX            Retain           Bound    runsdata/data-mongo-claim          runsdata-static-class            4d4h
    data-prometheus-pv                         2Gi        RWX            Recycle          Bound    monitoring/data-prometheus-claim   runsdata-static-class            151m
    data-static-pv                             1Gi        RWX            Retain           Bound    runsdata/data-static-claim         runsdata-static-class            7d15h
    pvc-02f5ce74-db7c-40ba-b0e1-ac3bf3ba1b37   3Gi        RWX            Delete           Bound    runsdata/data-test-claim           runsdata-static-class            3d5h
    pvc-085ec0f1-6429-4612-9f71-309b94a94463   1Gi        RWX            Delete           Bound    runsdata/data-file-claim           runsdata-static-class            3d17h
    [root@localhost online-prometheus]# kubectl get pvc -n monitoring
    NAME                    STATUS   VOLUME               CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS            AGE
    data-prometheus-claim   Bound    data-prometheus-pv   2Gi        RWX            runsdata-static-class   151m
    [root@localhost online-prometheus]#
```

2. heketi and glusterfs

```
[root@localhost online-prometheus]# kubectl get pods -n runsdata|egrep "heketi|gluster"
glusterfs-5btbl                               1/1     Running   1          11d
glusterfs-7gmbh                               1/1     Running   3          11d
glusterfs-rmx7k                               1/1     Running   7          11d
heketi-78ccdb6fd-97tkv                        1/1     Running   2          10d
[root@localhost online-prometheus]#
```

3. storageClass define

```
---
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: runsdata-static-class
provisioner: kubernetes.io/glusterfs
allowVolumeExpansion: true
reclaimPolicy: Delete
parameters:
  resturl: "http://10.10.11.181:8080"
  volumetype: "replicate:3"
  restauthenabled: "true"
  restuser: "admin"
  restuserkey: "runsdata-gf-admin"
  #secretNamespace: "runsdata"
  #secretName: "heketi-secret"
```

Comment: what is this IP and port 10.10.11.181:8080 ? Heketi pod?

Comment: yes, I have solved it,thanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution is  create endpoints and service under the current namespace. Then we can use the service in the pv yaml like below:
[image]

```
[root@localhost gluster]# cat glusterfs-endpoints.yaml 
---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: glusterfs-cluster
  namespace: monitoring
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 172.16.5.150
  - ip: 172.16.5.151
  - ip: 172.16.5.152
  ports:
  - port: 1
    protocol: TCP
[root@localhost gluster]# cat glusterfs-service.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: glusterfs-cluster
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 1
[root@localhost gluster]#
```